# org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.zk.ZookeeperDiscoverySpi.spiStart(ZookeeperDiscoverySpi.java:446)

Tags: ignite

I was trying to start Apache ignite. with the following command

```
apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin\bin\ignite.bat D:\workspace\<application-name>\src\main\resources\ignite.xml
```

And got the following error :

```
D:\software>apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin\bin\ignite.bat D:\workspace\inca\inca-dbobjects-common\src\main\resources\ignite.xml
[12:59:08]    __________  ________________
12:59:08]   /  _/ ___/ |/ /  _/_  __/ __/
[12:59:08]  _/ // (7 7    // /  / / / _/
[12:59:08] /___/\___/_/|_/___/ /_/ /___/
[12:59:08]
[12:59:08] ver. 2.6.0#20180710-sha1:669feacc
[12:59:08] 2018 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation
[12:59:08]
[12:59:08] Ignite documentation: http://ignite.apache.org
[12:59:08]
[12:59:08] Quiet mode.
[12:59:08]   ^-- Logging to file 'D:\software\apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin\work\log\ignite-35bf38b9.0.log'
[12:59:08]   ^-- Logging by 'JavaLogger [quiet=true, config=null]'
[12:59:08]   ^-- To see **FULL** console log here add -DIGNITE_QUIET=false or "-v" to ignite.{sh|bat}
[12:59:08]
[12:59:08] OS: Windows 10 10.0 amd64
[12:59:08] VM information: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_221-b11 Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.221-b11
[12:59:08] Configured plugins:
[12:59:08]   ^-- None
[12:59:08]
[12:59:08] Configured failure handler: [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0]]
[12:59:08] Message queue limit is set to 0 which may lead to potential OOMEs when running cache operations in FULL_ASYNC or PRIMARY_SYNC modes due to message queues growth on sender and receiver sides.
[12:59:08] Security status [authentication=off, tls/ssl=off]
[12:59:09] Started write-ahead log manager in NONE mode, persisted data may be lost in a case of unexpected node failure. Make sure to deactivate the cluster before shutdown.
[12:59:10,361][SEVERE][main][IgniteKernal] Got exception while starting (will rollback startup routine).

 [SEVERE][main][IgniteKernal] Got exception while starting (will rollback startup routine).
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/curator/utils/PathUtils
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.zk.ZookeeperDiscoverySpi.spiStart(ZookeeperDiscoverySpi.java:446)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:297)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:915)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1721)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1028)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2014)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1723)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1151)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:1069)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:955)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:854)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:724)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:693)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:352)
    at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:301)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.curator.utils.PathUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 15 more
[12:59:10] Ignite node stopped OK [uptime=00:00:02.961]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/curator/utils/PathUtils
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.zk.ZookeeperDiscoverySpi.spiStart(ZookeeperDiscoverySpi.java:446)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:297)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:915)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1721)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1028)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2014)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1723)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1151)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:1069)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:955)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:854)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:724)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:693)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:352)
    at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:301)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.curator.utils.PathUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 15 more
Failed to start grid: org/apache/curator/utils/PathUtils
Note! You may use 'USER_LIBS' environment variable to specify your classpath.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to move `ignite-zookeeper` directory from `libs/optional/` to `libs/` to make ZooKeeper dependencies available for Ignite code.